# jersey why reponse 404 instead of validation message when I missing parameter

Tags: jersey

```
@Path("report/v1")
public class ReportService {

    @Path("report")
    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public ReportResponse report(@NotNull @QueryParam("startDate") String startDate,
                                    @NotNull @QueryParam("endDate") String endDate,
                                    @NotNull(message = "{param.invalid.periodType}") @QueryParam("periodType") String periodType) {
        PublisherResponse res = new PublisherResponse();
```

I called method like below..

http://localhost:8080/report/v1/report?startDate=20140101&endDate=20140505

I expected validation error because periodType is missing. but returned 404.

How can i fix?

Comment: Which Jersey version are you using? And are you sure it's a 404 and not a 400?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make some assumptions.

- **Assumption 1:** You're using Jersey 2.x with it's [Bean Validation support](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html)
- **Assumption 2:** You're actually getting a 400 Bad Request, and not a 404 Not Found

The default behavior for the validation feature is to send a 400 Bad Request (that doesn't get mapped to a response). If we want Jersey to send it's validation error responses, we need to set the following property to true

```
property(ServerProperties.BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE, true);
```

See more at [Configuring Bean Validation Support](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html#d0e13314)